# clearInterval/run function only once not working

Tags: javascript

The function and `console.log("a")` keep firing when I repeatedly move out of `trw` and moving back in, it just doesn't stop. How do I make the function stop after I've called `onblur` once?

```js
var Hello = false;
var looper = setInterval(function() {
    if (!Hello) {
        trw.onblur = function() {
            console.log("a");
            clearInterval(looper);
            Hello = true; 
        }
    }
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use listener inside the interval better use outside

```js
var Hello = false;
var looper = setInterval(function() {
  if (!Hello) {
    console.log("a");
  }
}, 1);

document.getElementById('trw').onblur = function() {
  console.log("stopped");
  clearInterval(looper);
  Hello = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="trw">
```